# Intercept fulfillment response

Tags: dialogflow-es

Im using fulfillment to get data from database. And I have integrated my bot with facebook.

And currently I'm customizing db response as per facebook in my api itself and sending it to the dialogflow. 
And I want to integrate it with skype too.

Now my question is, can I customise my api response in dialogflow instead of in API. As I want to integrate my bot with multiple platforms so accordingly their response will be formatted as per facebook or skype. 
So i will need to create another api for skype too. I want to avoid this.

So I want to get output from my api and format it in dialogflow itself using custom payload. So is it possible to work in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Sure! You get the stored data using your API and then you format the response for the platforms you are going to use. In [this example](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#response), the payload contains different responses for Google Assistant, Facebook and Slack.

Also, take a look at [this NodeJS library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) which makes easier develop your fulfillment code.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in .net? Im using .net at the backend.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/), Google Cloud Functions can only be written in NodeJS and Python

Comment: You can use any language you want - as long as you can receive JSON and send JSON. But this starts to turn into a different question.